# Variety of multiple column indices on my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table with more than 5 million rows (and growing day by day) and I am trying to decide on which indices to create on this table according to the most common queries. Here is the summary of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
    entityId CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    userId CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    status TINYINT NOT NULL,
    acked BIT NOT NULL,
    createdAt BIGINT NOT NULL)
```

In fact, table has some more columns but I have only written the ones which are used while querying. Here is the list of queries which are called most.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y AND acked = w ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
```

**Query 4:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y AND acked = w
```

**Query 5:**

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
```

**Query 6:**

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE userId = 'x' AND createdAt < y ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
```

Here are the index alternatives:

**Index1:** (userId ASC, status ASC, acked ASC)

**Index2:** (userId ASC, createdAt ASC, status ASC, acked ASC)

**Index3:** (userId ASC, createdAt ASC)

**Index4:** (userId ASC)

I am running EXPLAIN command of MySQL Workbench on queries after constructing index combinations. Here are my questions:

**1.** I have used only Index5 for testing and executed query 5. Workbench says "Cost Hint: Medium - partial index scan" while using Index3. And displays only userId on "used key parts". However, when i drop index3 and add index4 instead, query5 slows down significantly. Therefore, although it is obvious that order by part benefits from its index, I am confused due to explain report of workbench. Are ORDER BY statements directly uses indices?

**2.** If answer to question 1 is 'yes', I consider using Index1 and Index2 together to make all 6 queries above to be able to use. Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 3 indexes for *that* set of `SELECTs`.

```
SELECT * FROM entity
        WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity
        WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y
-->     INDEX(userId, status, createdAt) -- or
        INDEX(status, userId, createdAt)

SELECT * FROM entity
             WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y AND acked = w
             ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity
             WHERE userId = 'x' AND status = y AND acked = w
-->          INDEX(status, userId, acked, createdAt)
-- This index won't work well on the first queries because `acked` is in the way.
-- My first index won't work well on these selects because it needs acked.
--    Again, keep createdAt last; shuffle the others in any way.

SELECT * FROM entity
         WHERE userId = 'x' ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z
SELECT * FROM entity
         WHERE userId = 'x' AND createdAt < y ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT z 
-->      INDEX(userId, createdAt)
```

Your Index3 is redundant because it is handled by your Index2.  However Index2 is not very useful because the `ORDER BY` part is not *last*.  That is, the fields after `createdAt` won't be used.

Most of this is covered in my [cookbook blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  It says

1. Handle all the "=" fields of the `WHERE`
2. Then you get one more crack -- the `ORDER BY` or the `createdAt < y`.

Comment: Any of my 3 indexes will "help" all the `SELECTs` (because of at least `userId`), but not be optimal.

Comment: `ASC` is the only thing that MySQL does in indexes, so it is 'noise'.